# wp_insert_post returns int(0)

Tags: wp-insert-post

if I run the following code it returns me an int(0). Wordpress creates the Post but with an empty post_title although the $name variable is filled.

```
$postID = wp_insert_post(array(
    "post_title" => $name,
    "post_status" => "publish",
    "post_type" => "mycustomposttype",
), true);
var_dump($postID);
```

Answer (score 7):

According to the notes on the codex [**`wp_insert_post()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#notes)

> **post_title and post_content are required**

If you want the content to be empty, you can write your `wp_insert_post` args array thus:

```
$postID = wp_insert_post(array(
    "post_title"  => $name,
    "post_status" => "publish",
    "post_content => " ",
    "post_type" => "mycustomposttype",
), true);
```

Comment: Also incorrect encoding could leads same result. Sanitize fields always.